# Linq performance parsing XML file

Tags: c#, xml, performance, linq

I need to parse an XML file  (1~10 MB); I am using `XDocument` for the purpose.

At the moment I am using `Linq` to query the XML document, but I need to improve the performance of my application and I thought to replace the `Linq` query with *old style loops*, but I did not have any boost.

Following is a piece of code with the most called query:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("filename.xml");
string def = "Version";
XElement xelm;

stopwatch.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    xelm = xdoc.Descendants("def").Where(d => d.Attribute("name").Value == def).Single();

stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);


stopwatch.Restart();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    foreach (var elm in xdoc.Descendants("def"))
    {
        if (elm.Attribute("name").Value == def)
        {
            xelm = elm;
            break;
        }
    }
}

stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

The elapsed time is pretty much the same for both versions, and for me this result is quite strange since I thought that the `Where` method of `Linq` has to create a new list when invoked.

Why both versions have the same performace? Is there a way to improve the original code?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx

Comment: Is the documents structure well known (every time the same)?

Comment: @Shnugo no, unfortunately it can change at runtime.

Comment: If `XDocument` is too slow, try scanning through the file with `XmlReader`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518266/xmlreader-reading-xml-file-based-on-attribute-value

Comment: [`Enumerable.Single`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) throws an exception if > 1 item is in the enumerable, and so must needs scan the entire collection.  Your manual loop breaks as soon as the first match is found.  Which do you want?

Comment: If the document is loaded only once but changed many times in memory, consider maintaining a lookup table of element names & attributes to elements.  I *think* you should be able to use the [`XObject.Changed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.changed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to keep the dictionary updated, though I've never tried it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ uses [deferred (lazy) execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx), which means that it only iterates through collections *once* and only when it needs to.

> Deferred execution can greatly improve performance when you have to manipulate large data collections, especially in programs that contain a series of chained queries or manipulations. In the best case, deferred execution enables only a single iteration through the source collection.

In this case, there is no new list being generated from your `Where` clause. In fact, the compiled version of your LINQ statement will function in almost the same way as your `foreach` statement.

**Edit:** My only idea about improving performance is to follow Robert McKee's answer, which says that you should use `.First()` instead of `.Single()` to not have to iterate through your entire list. Beyond that, I'm not sure what else you *can* do, except use a different library or a different language.

Comment: @Nick - Can you describe your performance scenario a little more?  Are you loading the document into memory once and running many queries, or loading and running only one query?  Is the `"def"` node a high-level node or a leaf node?  You say the document structure can change, but by how much?  Any way to cut down the scope of the search?

Comment: The document is loaded once at starup. "Def" can easily be a leaf node, but there art not so many level of deepness (4/5). New nodes are frequently added.

Answer (score 1):

Switch `.Single()` to `.First()` and it should perform much better.  Your for-loop is almost exactly like what `.First()` will do, while `.Single` is more like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    foreach (var elm in xdoc.Descendants("def"))
    {
        if (elm.Attribute("name").Value == def)
        {
            if (xelm!=null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            xelm = elm;
        }
    }
    if (xelm==null)
       throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

which will continue to traverse the document until it either finds another match (and throws an exception), or hits the end of the document.

You could possibly try using PLINQ, but you'll need to do extensive peformance testing, as there are a large number of factors that play into PLINQ's performance changes, including the hardware it runs on, and the structure of the document, etc.

```
stopwatch.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    xelm = xdoc.AsParallel()
        .Descendants("def")
        .Where(d => d.Attribute("name").Value == def)
        .Single();

stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Id be surprised if OP would see a significant difference: judging from the results of the loop (which terminates early) there should be very little difference.

Comment: True.  I wonder if it's never finding a match and both are traversing the entire document before returning null.

Comment: `Single` [throws an exception if there is not exactly one element in the sequence.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so it must be finding exactly one match.

Comment: @dbc You are correct.  Ok, perhaps it's the last one in the document.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize your situation:

1. You load a large `XDocument` at startup.
2. You run many linear searches through the `XDocument` to find nodes by name and attribute value.
3. Nodes can be added or removed after being loaded.
4. The performance of repeated linear searches is too slow.

In that case, it would appear to be necessary to put the nodes in some sort of lookup table to reduce the scope of the search.  The difficulty here is that that your document is changed after being loaded, so some mechanism would be needed to keep the tables up to date.  Luckily the [`XObject.Changing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.changing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`XObject.Changed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.changed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the `XDocument` itself can be used for that purpose.

For instance, the following class can be used to look up `XElement` nodes by name, and will dynamically update its lookup tables when nodes are added or removed, or node names are changed:

```
public class XDocumentRepository
{
    readonly XDocument doc;
    readonly Dictionary<XName, List<XElement>> elementsByName = new Dictionary<XName, List<XElement>>();

    public XDocument Document { get { return doc; } }

    public IEnumerable<XElement> ElementsByName(XName name)
    {
        return elementsByName.Items(name);
    }

    public XDocumentRepository(XDocument doc)
    {
        if (doc == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.doc = doc;
        doc.Changing += new EventHandler<XObjectChangeEventArgs>(doc_Changing);
        doc.Changed += new EventHandler<XObjectChangeEventArgs>(doc_Changed);
        AddAll(doc.Root);
    }

    private void AddAll(XElement root)
    {
        foreach (var element in root.DescendantsAndSelf())
            elementsByName.AddItem(element.Name, element);
    }

    private void RemoveAll(XElement root)
    {
        foreach (var element in root.DescendantsAndSelf())
            elementsByName.RemoveItem(element.Name, element);
    }

    void doc_Changed(object sender, XObjectChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        XElement xSender = sender as XElement;
        if (xSender != null && xSender.Document == doc)
        {
            switch (e.ObjectChange)
            {
                case XObjectChange.Add:
                case XObjectChange.Remove:
                    AddAll(xSender);
                    break;

                case XObjectChange.Name:
                    elementsByName.AddItem(xSender.Name, xSender);
                    break;

                case XObjectChange.Value:
                    break;

                default:
                    Debug.Assert(false, "unknown ObjectChange");
                    break;
            }
        }
        // If an attribute value were changed, sender would be an XAttribute
    }

    void doc_Changing(object sender, XObjectChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        XElement xSender = sender as XElement;
        if (xSender != null)
        {
            switch (e.ObjectChange)
            {
                case XObjectChange.Add:
                case XObjectChange.Remove:
                    RemoveAll(xSender);
                    break;

                case XObjectChange.Name:
                    elementsByName.RemoveItem(xSender.Name, xSender);
                    break;

                case XObjectChange.Value:
                    break;

                default:
                    Debug.Assert(false, "unknown ObjectChange");
                    break;
            }
        }
        // If an attribute value were changed, sender would be an XAttribute
    }
}

public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void AddItem<TKey, TValueList, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValueList> listDictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
        where TValueList : IList<TValue>, new()
    {
        if (listDictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        TValueList values;
        if (!listDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out values))
            listDictionary[key] = values = new TValueList();
        values.Add(value);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TValue> Items<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> listDictionary, TKey key)
    {
        if (listDictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        List<TValue> list;
        if (!listDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list))
            return Enumerable.Empty<TValue>();
        return list;
    }

    public static bool RemoveItem<TKey, TValueList, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValueList> listDictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
        where TValueList : IList<TValue>, new()
    {
        if (listDictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        TValueList values;
        if (!listDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out values))
            return false;
        return values.Remove(value);
    }
}
```

This only handles querying elements by name, but you could extend this idea to attribute values as well.

And then use it like:

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        string filePath = @"filename.xml";

        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
        var repository = new XDocumentRepository(xdoc);

        string defName = "def";
        string defValue = "Some Test Value For Querying";

        Test(repository, defName, defValue, null); // Assert element not found.

        var test = new XElement(defName, new XAttribute("name", defValue));

        // Find the first deepest node in the document, for testing purposes.
        var node = xdoc.Descendants().OrderByDescending(e => e.AncestorsAndSelf().Count()).First();
        node.Add(test);

        Test(repository, defName, defValue, test); // Assert element found

        test.Attribute("name").Value = "fobar";
        Test(repository, defName, defValue, null); // Assert element not found when attribute value is changed

        test.Attribute("name").Value = defValue;
        Test(repository, defName, defValue, test); // Assert element found when attribute value restored

        test.Name = "flubber";
        Test(repository, defName, defValue, null); // Assert element not found when name changed

        test.Name = defName;
        Test(repository, defName, defValue, test); // Assert element found when name restored

        var parent = test.Parent;
        var parentParent = parent.Parent;

        test.Remove();
        Test(repository, defName, defValue, null); // Assert element not found when removed.

        parent.Add(test);
        Test(repository, defName, defValue, test); // Assert element found when added back

        if (parentParent != null)
        {
            parent.Remove();
            Test(repository, defName, defValue, null); // Assert element not found when parent removed.

            parentParent.Add(parent);
            Test(repository, defName, defValue, test); // Assert element found when parent added back.
        }
    }

    static void Test(XDocumentRepository repository, string elementName, string attributeValue, XElement expectedValue)
    {
        var xelm1 = repository.Document.Descendants(elementName).Where(d => (string)d.Attribute("name") == attributeValue).SingleOrDefault();
        var xelm2 = repository.ElementsByName(elementName).Where(d => (string)d.Attribute("name") == attributeValue).SingleOrDefault();
        Debug.Assert(xelm1 == xelm2 && xelm1 == expectedValue); // No assert
    }
```

Note that, because dictionaries are being used, the order in which elements are returned is undefined.  If multiple elements match any given query, you can sort them into document order by using [`XNode.CompareDocumentOrder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.comparedocumentorder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give a try with this. I tried this on my machine and I can see it to be beneficial if the order is not really important to you though i did not print out the elements being selected. Depending on what your  actual code is you might need to take care of synchronization using locks.

```
stopwatch.Restart();
Parallel.For(0, 1000, i =>
{
   foreach (var elm in xdoc.Descendants("def"))
   {
        if (elm.Attribute("name").Value == "def")
        {
               xelm = elm;
               break;
         }
    }
});
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Please note that parallelising the line "  foreach (var elm in xdoc.Descendants("def")) " using Parallel.foreach did not seem to give a good performance on my machine which could be due to the fact that the overhead in parallelising this is high (my guess).